# I am using pactnet and want to post the contract to pack broker

Tags: .net, pact-broker

I am having a pact file generated by using pactNet(I am a C# programmer), now how do I post the pact file to pact-broker.
I have done a lot of reading using Curl, ruby and java (with Gradle) for this purpose but did not see anything equivalent for C#. 
Is there anyone achieve this before and any guidance is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Check [PactNet documentation](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net#publishing-pacts-to-a-broker):

```
var pactPublisher = new PactPublisher("http://test.pact.dius.com.au", new PactUriOptions("username", "password"));
pactPublisher.PublishToBroker(
    "..\\..\\..\\Samples\\EventApi\\Consumer.Tests\\pacts\\event_api_consumer-event_api.json",
    "1.0.2", new [] { "master" });
```

I think you should consider publishing pacts as a CI task of Consumer's build.